# How to remove Hash(#) in URL on angular 7

Tags: angular, url, hash, angular7

I am new in `angular 7` in my project i want to remove #(hash) in `URL`

This is my actual `url` https://dev.abc.com/web/

But when i access this `url` it add #(hash) like this https://dev.abc.com/web/#/

This my `routing .module.js` code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from '../views/home/home.component';
import { CubberComponent } from '../views/cubber/cubber.component';
import { SignupComponent } from '../views/cubber/signup/signup.component';
import { SigninComponent } from '../views/cubber/signin/signin.component';
import { MyinformationComponent } from '../views/cubber/myinformation/myinformation.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from '../views/cubber/profile/profile.component';
import { PasswordComponent } from '../views/cubber/password/password.component';
import { MyaddressComponent } from '../views/cubber/myaddress/myaddress.component';
import { AuthGuard } from '../service/auth/auth.guard';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../views/cubber/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { MylistingComponent } from '../views/cubber/mylisting/mylisting.component';
import { MyavailablityComponent } from '../views/cubber/myavailablity/myavailablity.component';
import { MyphotosComponent } from '../views/cubber/myphotos/myphotos.component';
import { MypaymentComponent } from '../views/cubber/mypayment/mypayment.component';
export const routes: Routes = [
     {
          path: '',
          component: HomeComponent,
          pathMatch: 'full'
     },    
     {
          path: 'signup',
          component: SignupComponent,
          data: { title: 'signup' }
     }
];

@NgModule({
     imports: [
          RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
          exports: []
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
     constructor(private router: Router) {
          this.router.errorHandler = (error: any) => {
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
          };
     }
}
```

I refer some blog it said in `@NgModule` add `userHash:false` like this

```
@NgModule({
     imports: [
          RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{userHash:false})],
          exports: []
})
```

I am not sure it is working or not.

> Please help me to remove #(hash) in my `url`

Answer (score 3):

its an PathLocationStrategy is a default location strategy in Angular.

Check your module imports, it can also be overridden by providing the { useHash: true } as the second argument of the `RouterModule.forRoot`:

```
imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })
]
```

Also note that when using PathLocationStrategy you need to configure your web server to serve index.html (app's entry point) for all requested locations.